# Learning background yet still showing static object through webcam

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I am working on a university project where we have a table with glass surface, a webcam, and IR spots underneath.
We want to detect certain gestures such as:

- 1, 2, 3 fingers
- 3 fingertips

This is how a hand looks through the camera:
[image: Hand IR webcam image]

When the camera initialise it learns the background and subtracts it, going from
[image: Webcam background subtraction ini]

to this:
[image: Hand on webcam background subtraction]

The hand, however, is also "learned" and disappears rather quickly.
We want to the program to learn the background, but will not store the hand as part of the background as it will be static.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

What we have tried: playing with the learning rate, blurring, morphology.
Code included below.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char)
{
Mat frame; //current frame
Mat fgMaskMOG; //fg mask generated by MOG method
int frameNum = 0;
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2; //MOG2 Background subtractor

//pMOG = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG(); //MOG approach
pMOG2 = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(20, 16, false); //MOG2 approach

VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera

if (!cap.isOpened()) // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

for (;;)
{
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    if (!cap.read(frame)) {
        cerr << "Unable to read next frame." << endl;
        continue;
    }
    imshow("orig", frame);
    ++frameNum;
    pMOG2->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG, -1);

    imshow("frame", fgMaskMOG);

    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;
}
// the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Just an idea: Why not use an initialization phase of e.g. 10 seconds to learn the background and than disable the "learning" and just use what was "learned" in the init phase as subtraction?

Comment: You have to make a choice. Do you want a hand that doesn't move for five minutes to be continuously detected for those five minutes? If yes, then you can't subtract something out just because it's been there for five minutes. Decide what you want the behavior to be first.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot Kraemer. I implemented that the program applies and records the masked image for 200 frames. Right now it does not want to store it as video (I think this might have to do with the 8bit nature of the mask). However, I was successful in rendering 200 images.
I am having trouble using the sequence of images as a mask to compare to the live video. Any further suggestions?
Edits: clarified last sentence